# How to rewrite old url with a period, question mark and equals in it?

Tags: regex, nginx

My old website has url's like this:

```
/canada1/bc_british_columbia/weather.php?db=90
```

I'm trying to use an Nginx rewrite like this:

```
location ~ /canada1/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/(.*) {
        rewrite ^/canada1/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)$ /atemplates/weather/weather_forecast.php?region=$1&location=$2 last;
}
```

I can get the $1 fine but the $2 I can't seem to figure the regex out so I can get that "90" portion at the end of the url. I guess I'm wondering what to replace that (.*) with. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Anything from the `?` onwards is the query string and is not considered when matching the URI to a `location` block or a `rewrite` statement. If you need to use arguments, see [the `$arg_` variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try out the following code,

```
server {
   ...

   location ~ /canada1/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/.* {
      rewrite ^/canada1/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/.* /atemplates/weather/weather_forecast.php?region=$1&location=$arg_db last;
   }

   ...
}
```

**Edit**: Make sure the above location is before location ~ .php block, as location with regular expression are processed in order, and the first matching one is executed, [Read Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Works pretty good if I take out that period. I think I need just a little more help to defeat that period. Appreciated.

Comment: ... The period in the url I mean.

Comment: Hi Satys, your answer is the correct one, but I had other issues as well. It turns out I also had the location blocks out of order and the location ~ \.php$ { ... } was grabbing the url with a .php extension first. Once I re-ordered it now works fine. Reference: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075348/nginx-rewrite-not-working-with-php-extension)

Comment: Actually, I wanted to mention that, but I thought you might be knowing, and very rare people add any location after php block, i'll edit the answer for the same