# Nginx rewrite not working with .php extension

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a url rewrite via this code:

```
location ~ /canada1/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/.* {
        rewrite ^/canada1/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/.* /atemplates/weather/weather_forecast.php?region=$1&location=$arg_db last;
}
```

With this url:

```
/canada1/bc_british_columbia/weather.php?db=90
```

I've narrowed down the issue to the .php portion. Whatever I stick in there to replace it works fine as expected i.e. .phd .phq .abcdefg ... works fine. What do I need to do to make that thing rewrite with that .php extension?

Thanks for your help.

Reference: [How to rewrite old url with a period, question mark and equals in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064214/how-to-rewrite-old-url-with-a-period-question-mark-and-equals-in-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order.

If you want `location ~ /canada1/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/.*` to take precedence over `location ~ \.php$`, then you need to place the first one **before** the second one, in your configuration file.

For example:

```
location ~ /canada1/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/.* {
    ...
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Ah... thank you Richard, worked like a charm. I'm glad it was something simple like the location order... those little things tend to trip me up *sigh*